# How to find count of second degree followers in a database as below?

Tags: mysql

```
Followee Follower
A        B
B        C
B        D
B        E
A        F
F        G
F        H
B        H
```

how can query to find the count of 2nd degree followers of "A" which is 5 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

i think it's very easy

```
select count(distinct t1.Follower) 
    from t 
       join 
         t t1 
       on t.Follower=t1.Followee
  where t.Followee='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the name of the table be "follows". To find second degree followers count for "A":

```
select count(follower) from follows 
where followee in 
(select distinct follower from follows where followee='A')
```

If you want to find the count of second degree followers count for all the followees:

```
select f2.followee, count(f1.follower) 
from follows f1 inner join follows f2 
on f2.follower=f1.followee 
group by f2.followee
```

Comment: Both your queries yield A as having 6 second degree followers. This is incorrect.

Comment: @zzztimbo Yes! That's what I meant. If you want the result for only "A", then use query one. Use query two if you want the result for all the values ("A","B","C" etc.). The result of "A" is not supposed to change in both cases.

Comment: Both queries are incorrect because you don't take into consideration the removal of duplicate second degree followers, a second degree follower being the original followee, and the fact that a second degree follower can contain first degree followers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.followee,count(DISTINCT a.followee,b.follower) from following a
left join following b
on b.followee = a.follower
left join following d
on d.followee = a.followee and d.follower = b.follower
where d.followee is null
GROUP BY a.followee
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the table's name is tbl.

```
SELECT count (distinct tbl.follower) 
FROM tbl 
JOIN 
(SELECT distinct follower FROM tbl WHERE followee = 'A') AS tbl2
ON tbl.followee = tbl2.follower
```

The answer is 5.